# Correctly conecting two actions (Gerund)?

Tags: past-perfect, past-continuous

I want to say that someone put her baby to sleep and was reading her book while she was sitting in the sitting room.

The Continuous can't be followed by the Gerund. So, I can't say:

> *His wife, who had just put her baby to sleep, was sitting in the sitting room, reading a book.*

Is it acceptable to say:

> *His wife, who had just put her baby to sleep, was sitting in the sitting room and reading a book.*

Are there other possible variants?

Comment: `reading book` => `reading a book` in both sentences

Comment: I don't know who told you *Continuous can't be followed by the Gerund*, but even if that might apply in *some* contexts (I've no idea what it even *means*), it doesn't apply to your example. Take, for example, [*Otis was sitting on the dock of the bay, watching the tide roll away.*](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/otisredding/sittinonthedockofthebay.html) I won't hear a word against that, on musical ***or*** grammatical grounds.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I meant, I couldn't say "His wife, who had just put her baby to sleep, was `sitting reading` a book in the sitting room." inspite of the variants above, could I? So, we use gerund as a "turnover of the participle".

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking about. There's nothing wrong with the example in your above comment - except I'd probably say *His wife, who had just put her baby to sleep, was sitting reading a book in the **lounge***, simply because the repetition of ***sitting*** comes across as "clumsy". But that's really got nothing to do with gerunds (not that I know or care whether the compound noun ***sitting** room* involves a gerund usage anyway).

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, there is absolutely nothing wrong with either of the example sentences you gave.  Both are completely acceptable and sound quite natural, and you can use either one you want.

> The Continuous can't be followed by the Gerund.

This is technically true, but I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding here of what "gerund" means.  A *gerund* is a verb (or verb clause) which is being *used as a noun* (for example, as the subject or object of a sentence).  So, for example, in the sentence:

> Reading a book is fun

"Reading a book" is a gerund here, because it is a verb clause which is being used as a noun to be the subject of the sentence "(noun) is fun".

However, in your sentence:

> ... was sitting in the sitting room, reading a book.

Here, "reading a book" is *not* a gerund, because it is *not being used as a noun*.  "Reading" in this case is actually a *present participle*.  This can be confusing in English because both *gerunds* and *present participles* are generally constucted by adding "ing" to the end of a verb, but they are used in different ways (and thus have different rules).

And it is actually perfectly acceptable to attach multiple participle phrases after a leading "is"/"was"/etc like this, so this has the same meaning (and is just as acceptable) as:

> ... was sitting in the sitting room, *and was* reading a book.

In fact, some might actually say that it feels somewhat smoother (and perhaps a bit more casual), as it is just a less wordy way to say the same thing.